# Java - Finding the closest node in a LinkedList

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the closest number in a LinkedList in Java. I've come up with code that sorts the LinkedList (which in my case is populated with random numbers from 0-300) and then iterates through the loop, setting the integer "nearest" to the nearest previous number in the sorted list. However, I run into an issue when the nearest number is larger than the starting number but closer to it than the previous number, as my code does not check if the larger number is closer. How would I go about checking if the higher number is closer than the last previous number?

I apologize if the answer is rather clear, I'm pretty new to Java and I've been trying to solve this for so long my mind is blank. I assume the answer has something to do with the absolute value of the difference between the two, but I'm stumped here.

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

int starting = number.nextInt(300);
int nearest = 0;

Collections.sort(list);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    if (list.get(i) <= starting)
    {
        nearest = list.get(i);
    }
}

System.out.print("The closest element of the list is " + nearest + ".");
```

Comment: You're finding the closest value to your `starting` value?

Comment: You do not need to sort list to achieve your goal. And you could use `Math.abs()` to find nearest

Comment: Since you are currently sorting the list, the nearest number will be the one right next to it.

Comment: @CHenry It need not be. Take [8, 10, 15] and you want to find nearest to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the lowest difference found (so far) between any number and the starting one. This can be done by using `Math.abs` to get the absolute value between two numbers.

You can pick the closest numbers based on the lowest difference.

```
int diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (Math.abs(starting - list.get(i)) < diff) {
        nearest = list.get(i);
        diff = Math.abs(starting - list.get(i));
    }
}

System.out.print("The closest element of the list is " + nearest + ".");
```

This will pick the lower number if there are two possible choices.

*Example:* [9,10,11] and you start with 10, this will pick 9.

To pick 11, just change `<` to `<=` in the `if` condition

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to sort numbers to find closest to your goal. Just search for one with the closest absolute difference with your goal. This is a one-liner with Java 8:

```
Integer result = integers
    .stream()
    .min(Comparator.comparing(x -> Math.abs(x - goal)))
    .orElse(null);
```

That's essentially `O(n)`. Sorting will be typically something like `O(n*log n)` so unless you need sorted array for other purposes, sorting is not reasonable from the time complexity POV here.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you're finding the closest value to your `starting` value.

You don't need to sort your list.

Try this:

```
int nearest = 0;
int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i : list) {
  int d = Math.abs(i - starting);
  if (d < distance) {
    nearest = i;
    distance = d;
  }
}

System.out.print("The closest element of the list is " + nearest + ".");
```